# Initial feasible solution for barrier method

Tags: numerical-optimization

From this [example page 9](https://web.stanford.edu/group/sisl/k12/optimization/MO-unit5-pdfs/5.7interiorpenalty.pdf) It said set initial feasible solution at 2
here's barrier function:
$$T(x)=\frac{100}{x}+\frac{1}{r}(\frac{-1}{x-5})$$
after derivative:
$$\frac{\delta T}{\delta x}=\frac{1}{r(x-5)^2}-\frac{100}{x^2}$$
we show x in terms of r (we skip the step of algebra):
$$x=\frac{-50r}{1-10r}$$
then we set r to infinite we get x =5
x never inolve the iteration
Why we need an initial value 
and form my refrence book it said barrier function like that:
$$T(x)=\frac{100}{x}-r(\frac{1}{x-5})$$
but the result gives -5 I think because it is absent of lower bound 
which one should we choose for barrier method

Answer (score 1):

Simplifying your equation we obtain
$x^2(1-100r)+100rx-2500r=0$
using the quadratic formula we get
$$x_1=\frac{50 \left(10 r-\sqrt{r}\right)}{100 r-1}$$
$$x_2=\frac{50 \left(10 r+\sqrt{r}\right)}{100 r-1}$$